# Why is the Koenigs function analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

Consider the Koenigs function

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

Why is it analytic ?

How to prove it is analytic ?

I assume the Weierstrass M-test is used.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

In fact , i do not know another way to show it !?

Maybe this relates https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend *A History of Complex Dynamics* by Daniel S. Alexander. Chapter 3, section 5, is on pages 46-47 and called Koenigs' solution of the Schroder Equation. There is then a footnote, he says the proof by Koenigs is quite long, a short proof can be found in Milnor, *Dynamics in One Complex Variable*.

See if I can find where Milnor puts it; right, in the Third Edition, Theorem 8.2 is called Koenigs Linerization. Page 77, mostly pages 76-79
[EARLIER EDITION](https://books.google.com/books?id=QiDpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=milnor%20koenigs%20linearization%20if%20the%20multiplier&source=bl&ots=76WXzvl_x-&sig=1qIOKXwOr6zZbOQuHf5Qo_sCwsI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWk8zsjdLRAhVhwlQKHTbrDrYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=milnor%20koenigs%20linearization%20if%20the%20multiplier&f=false)

[image]

Comment: What does it mean ; " the diagram is commutative " ? I know nothing about diagrams.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167033/meaning-of-commutative-diagram